# how to send a message to multiple contact in one thread

Tags: android, sms, mms

how to send a message to multiple contact in one thread?

eg:

sendto:NO1,NO2,NO3

The results in threads table like below:

```
recipient_ids:1 2 3

type：1
```

solution  renew(20121213):

Build the android system by myself ,and use the libary  in

```
out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES
```

and reference the stock mms app ,creat or get new thread id with

```
getOrCreateThreadId(Context context, String recipient)
```

recipient: a comma separated list of numbers

Comment: @talhakosen yes,i want send message to multiple contacts in one conversation

Comment: ok you can use the code in my answer

Comment: @talhakosen
Does SmsManager sendTextMessage with loop create many thread row in threads table? I need them in "one conversation"

Comment: @Nirav Ranpara i try with SmsManager with loop ,it create many row in thread table,which is not i want

Comment: Yes you can send message in a loop

Comment: @talhakosen i have tried it with loop,but the thread table field :recipient_ids,just log  one recipient id of the numbers. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the android system by myself ,and use the libary in

```
out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES
```

and reference the stock mms app ,creat or get new thread id with

```
getOrCreateThreadId(Context context, String recipient)
```

recipient: a comma separated list of numbers

Answer (score 0):

if it is an sms you can use below,

**MobNumber** is an Array

```
 for (int i = 0; i < MobNumber.size(); i++) 
        {
                 SmsManager sender=SmsManager.getDefault();
                 sender.sendTextMessage(MobNumber.get(i).toString(),null,Text , null, null);
         }
```

Comment: i have tried it with loop,but the thread table field :recipient_ids,just log one recipient id of the numbers. :(